# How do I save external JSON data to a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an JSON file (I cannot change), `data.json` that looks like:

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "AccountId": "1234",
            "ClientId": "12345567",
            "Amount": 140.68,
            "BalanceYear": "2015",
            "AccountName": "Master"
        },
    "Success": true,
    "Errors": null
}
```

I am bringing it into my .js file as such:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./data.json"></script>
```

And I want to iterate through it with `JSON.parse`.

My only issue is getting the data from the .json file to the `JSON.parse` function.

```
var mydata = JSON.parse(???);
```

Would anyone know how I can do this?